# Can I serve a ClickOnce application with Apache?

Tags: apache, deployment, clickonce

We're testing our ClickOnce deployed application internally on IIS (Internet Information Services), but we're wondering if we can deploy it to the wider internet using Apache on Linux so we can make use of our existing external website host.

If so, is there anything else I need to consider other than as specifying the correct mime types such as `.application` and `.deploy`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a number of people asking the same question starting around 2005, but here is the first google result - also discusses silverlight.

http://software.clempaul.me.uk/articles/clickonce/

As far as I can tell, however, the only thing you would need to worry about would be setting up the mime types and providing access to the files.

Comment: Great link, thanks! I've found that querying Google is a skill - most often I get exactly what I want but this time I'd drawn a couple of pages of rubbish including a promising forum post that dead-ended!

Comment: Upvoted you because you answered first, but try to append the reference to your post like @Don Kirkby did, just in case that website goes down... I'm from the future, late 2010, and had the same problem, luckily the website was still online :)

Answer (score 9):

The [Paul Clement](http://software.clempaul.me.uk/articles/clickonce/) article is the best description I've found. I also came across a topic in the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/htaccess.html#when) that suggests putting the configuration in the httpd.conf file instead of .htaccess files. Here are the lines I added to my httpd.conf file:

```
AddType application/x-ms-application .application
AddType application/manifest .manifest
AddType application/octet-stream .deploy
```