# ClickOnce, install from Web. What am I missing?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, clickonce

I'm trying to publish my app with ClickOnce to install from a Web page. I'm using a free server at "000webhost.com". But is not working. My files are uploaded but when I click on Install (from the publish.html page) I get a broken link, and when I click "launch" an XML file is opened in my browser. Apparently I'm missing something so elemental that no one bothers to talk about. I think I read somewhere that the server must have FrontPage extension installed. Any help will help.

**Edit:** Now I tried to install it from Internet Explorer. This time I didn't get a broken link but I got this error: "Cannot continue. The application is improperly formated. Contact the application vendor for assistance". So, still, any help will help. And by the way are they assuming everyone uses IE or why am I getting a broken link when using Chrome?

Comment: What's the URL of the broken link? Are you uploading all the files to the server?

Comment: This is my link: http://juaneco.webatu.com/HeliumInstall/publish.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the MIME type configuration for `.application` files on the Web server (probably you can't change it on a free service). The web server is sending the ClickOnce manifest as plain-text instead as application/octet-stream, so the browser just displays it instead of trying to launch it with the installer.

Comment: Sorry but, any idea where do am I supposed to check that?

Comment: In your webserver configuration, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93361/can-i-serve-a-clickonce-application-with-apache for apache

Comment: I don't think this server gives me access to that. I tried the solution on your link (uploaded a file called "something.htaccess" with the 7 lines of code as shown here: http://software.clempaul.me.uk/articles/clickonce/) but still got the same error.

Comment: Try sending your host an e-mail about your deployment issue. I suspect it's more of a configuration issue as Xint0 suggests with mention of how the web server is handling the MIME type configuration.

Comment: If the web server you are using is Apache, then a `.htaccess` file should help, but it should be named just `.htaccess`, not `something.htaccess`