# Deploying the Windows Form Application by Click Once

Tags: c#, clickonce

I knew nothing about ClickOnce and I tried to find more. I have an Windows Forms Application and I want to use a web server (http) to deploy it by click once for testing by customer.

I have Apache in my system to use my system as a web server (which is in XAMPP software)

I have several questions:

1. When I want to publish the application, must I copy it in specific directory?
2. Is there any free web server that I can use?
3. If there is, must I copy my application on web server? How?

BTW, If you know a detailed instruction about that ,may you introduced?

PS: I read [this reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms953320.aspx) completely.

Comment: You already have a free web server if you have XAMPP, why do you want another one? Make sure you set the [mime types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93361/can-i-serve-a-clickonce-application-with-apache) correctly, and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

1. You specify the location of your ClickOnce Application in Properties -> Publish. The Publishing Folder is the Location, where Visual Studio tries to save the published Location. If you are using a WebServer where you have to log in, Choose here a local path on your computer. The Installation Folder URL is the URL, where the ClickOnce Application is looking for Updates. This is the Url on the Server where you have to copy all the Files from the Publish Folder to, if its not the same.
2. I dont think that there is a free web server you can use. There are a few Services which are quit cheap but as you mentioned, you can use your own Server with XAMPP. I never used XAMPP so i cant help you their
3. Yes you have to copy your application to the Web Server. Im using WinSCP for that. Be sure to copy the files to the location you have set in the properties. If you are using XAMPP, you may copy the files locally to the XAMPP folder

There are no specific instructions i can mention. You will find everything in the Web. There are some useful articels at [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/)